# Hyperledger fabric Node js synchronising the block from channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have setup the hyper-ledger fabric network with chain-code its working fine.From the client end, i am using the fabric-node. Is there any method or way to sync the block one by one using fabric-node.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?   What have you tried?

Comment: i have created the channel events in one of my app which acts has service, using that service from channel events i get block details and i am storing in DB, Now lets assume my app service is down, so channel event also down from which i was getting block details. i ll miss the all the other transaction detail after the service was down. but when my app service is  up again,i need to get the block height from where my app service was stopped. is it possible ?